# Docker: When Checkstyles detects error, abort

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile, checkstyle

Hi I am editing my android docker instance which builds my android APK.

I want to add a checkstyle exception which should cause an abort if Any warnings occure.

I have it working in that it Runs checkstyle, but it just output warnings. I do not see a way of making these errors or halting the operation like Lint does. What should I add to my docker file?

```
java -jar ./styleguide/checkstyle-7.7-all.jar -c ./styleguide/rules/google_checks.xml .
```

As I do not have the google indentation I get 18k errors that look like

```
[WARN] pathstuff/./app/src/testRelease/java/com/app/BuildConfigReleaseTest.java:41: 'method def rcurly' has incorrect indentation level 4, expected level should be 2. [Indentation]
Audit done.
```

These are what I want to abort on. Preferably list all of them, but if we just list that they need to run checkstyles  -- that will be enough.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> I have it working in that it Runs checkstyle, but it just output warnings.

This is being overridden inside the `google_checks.xml` file. Checkstyle by default, will print everything as errors. If anything else comes up, then the configuration is overriding it.

> I do not see a way of making these errors

Open up `google_checks.xml` and look for the line similar to: `<property name="severity" value="warning"/>`

Change `warning` to `error` in the value attribute and it will print violations as errors.